# Is there a closed form solution for slope lines of bilinear function?

Tags: interpolation, bilinear-form

Given a bilinear function $f(x,y) = a + bx + cy + dxy$, is there a closed form solution for a slope line passing through point $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0, y_0))$? It can exclude degenerate cases, e.g. $b = c = d = 0$.

**Edit**

I call $f$ bilinear due to my application domain, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation), but the name is probably superfluous here, except that the domain can be restricted to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$. By slope line, I mean a curve that is everywhere orthogonal to the contours as defined in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line).

Comment: if you can explain this better, i imagine we can help you. I don't know why you call $f$ bilinear, and i don't know what you mean by a "slope line" or what it might have to do with $f$

Comment: Can you give us two points on the desired line?  (Perhaps also $(0,0,f(0,0))$?)

Comment: @WillJagy I added more details and a correction to my question.

Comment: @EricTowers In general case, I can give you only one point $(x_0, y_0, f(x_0,y_0))$, because I don't know how to calculate another one belonging to the same slope line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide through by $d;$ after that we have $d=1$ and new values for $b,c.$

Your curves are $$ xy + bx + c y = \; \; \mbox{something},  $$ OR
$$ (x+c)(y+b) = \; \; \mbox{thing},  $$

The orthogonal family are also hyperbolas,
$$ (x + c)^2 - (y + b)^2 =  \; \; \mbox{something} \; \; \mbox{else}  $$

At some point $(x,y),$ the gradient of the first function is
$$  (y + b, x + c), $$
the gradient of the second function is
$$  (2( x + c),-2(y+b) ). $$ So the dot product of the two gradients is zero.